# Plot Graphs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am learning data science at the moment. Just out of curiosity I wanted to know if it is possible to plot graphs in SQL from the existing data. I am using MySQL. If yes please guide me with a link or reference !

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, a database is for storing and retrieving data efficiently and safely. Not for other purposes.

Use any client application to retrieve the data the way you need it (from MySQL), and to graph it accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree strongly with @TheImpaler, here is a KLUDGE for making a bar graph:

```
mysql> SELECT city, population, REPEAT('x', population/200000) FROM `us` ORDER BY population DESC;
+----------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| city                       | population | REPEAT('x', population/200000)            |
+----------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| New York                   |    8107916 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| Los Angeles                |    3877129 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                       |
| Chicago                    |    2841952 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                            |
| Houston                    |    2027712 | xxxxxxxxxx                                |
| Philadelphia               |    1453268 | xxxxxxx                                   |
| Phoenix                    |    1428509 | xxxxxxx                                   |
| San Diego                  |    1287050 | xxxxxx                                    |
| San Antonio                |    1256810 | xxxxxx                                    |
| Dallas                     |    1211704 | xxxxxx                                    |
| San Jose                   |     897460 | xxxx                                      |
```

(Don't even think about a pie chart!)

Comment: I was looking for this trick for so long... thanks